# Zonal Statistics Spatial Join Raster to Polygon in Python

Tags: python, raster, zonal-statistics

- I have a data frame that consists of 3 polygons
- I have a raster with a single band

Seems like Zonal statistics as a table in ArcGIS does the job but I am using pure python script on this one; with no access to ArcPy.

how do I join the raster value (min, max, average, etc.) to the 3 polygons?

```py
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file("polygons.shp")
print("length of gdf: ", len(gdf))
# length of gdf: 3

def zonstats(gdf, raster_path):
    ...
    ...
    ...
    return gdf_joined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`rasterstats.zonal_stats`](https://pythonhosted.org/rasterstats/)

```
import geopandas as gpd
from rasterstats import zonal_stats

zones = "zones.shp"
values = "values.tif"

gdf = gpd.read_file(zones)
print(gdf.head())

stats = gpd.GeoDataFrame(zonal_stats(gdf, values, stats=["min", "max", "mean"]))
gdf = gdf.join(stats)

print(gdf.head())
```

Example output:

```
   id                                           geometry
0   1  POLYGON ((440819.096 3751134.570, 440983.634 3...
1   2  POLYGON ((441147.373 3751255.178, 441265.585 3...
2   3  POLYGON ((441438.110 3751077.860, 441789.549 3...
3   4  POLYGON ((440808.713 3750651.340, 440925.327 3...
4   5  POLYGON ((441174.530 3750450.061, 441371.017 3...
   id                                           geometry  ...    max        mean
0   1  POLYGON ((440819.096 3751134.570, 440983.634 3...  ...  173.0  133.909091
1   2  POLYGON ((441147.373 3751255.178, 441265.585 3...  ...  140.0  120.900000
2   3  POLYGON ((441438.110 3751077.860, 441789.549 3...  ...  165.0  122.714286
3   4  POLYGON ((440808.713 3750651.340, 440925.327 3...  ...  140.0  118.800000
4   5  POLYGON ((441174.530 3750450.061, 441371.017 3...  ...  173.0  122.555556
```

Comment: quick clarification; the ```zones.shp``` consists of more than 1 feature, am I correct?

Comment: @sutan yes zonal_stats returns as many records as there are features

Comment: If you're willing to use R from Python, the exactextractr package is much faster and does much more than rasterstats.

Comment: @sermomon that comment would be better as a complete answer with an example

Comment: @sermomon good to know, I'm not using R but some of my friends do. If you have an answer & example just as@user2856 suggested it'd be nice! thanks.

Comment: @user2856 ```zonal_stats(gdf, values)```  it works, but it's not ```gdf``` as the first arg, rather it should be the path of the zones; it should be ```zonal_stats(zones, values)```.

Comment: @sutan, no  it doesn't have to be a path as the first arg. You can pass a gdf (or path to a vector datasource, or a list of arcpy.Polygon shapes if you really want to). That code in my example is exactly what produced that output. You're better of passing the gdf, saves an extra filesystem read.

Comment: Here you can see a little tutorial about the use of exactextractr package: https://github.com/isciences/exactextractr It's pretty simple to use if you're familiar with R. But if you want to run R from Python via rpy2, for example, it'll be a bit more complicated.

Comment: @user2856 my bad, was inputing the wrong variable in my script. good to know, thanks!